# Server Timeout on Http GET on certain network

Tags: java, http-get, socket-timeout-exception

I am trying to make a get request in Java using HttpURLConnection.  The response is 200 when I am on my home network but on the company nework i am getting a connect timed out error (SocketTimeoutException) I changed the timeout to be 20 seconds and I am still getting this error after a few seconds.  The link is available when I view it in the browser on the same network that I am getting the timeout from the Java code, so I could it still be a firewall issue? Or something else? Here is my code:

```
    String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    URL obj = new URL("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode(); 
    System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);
```

Comment: does your company provide a proxy?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with proxies. If it's necessary, i'm sure they do but if I can see the response in my chrome browser on the same network, could it still be an issue?

Comment: It certainly could. If you mean Chrome on Windows, like IE/Edge it uses the system (Windows) proxy setting which can be set automatically by WPAD and/or group policy, or if this is a company-supplied computer just by configuring it. If the company network requires use of the proxy for HTTP, as many do for variously good or bad (and ugly!) reasons, then Chrome uses the proxy setting and works, but Java doesn't use it and fails. If you aren't on Windows, specify what you are on.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically an error produced by a firewall in your company's network. But if your browser is able to get to the internet, then your browser is using some proxy (likely the system proxy). So, you have to parametrize the JVM through the standard [Java network properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) to make it use the system proxy:

```
java -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true ...
```

Or, alternatively, find out which are the system proxy parameters (host, port, user and password) and pass them to the JVM:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=... -Dhttp.proxyPort=...
```